# Storing interfaces in object

Tags: javascript, types, typescript

Imagine I have the following interfaces

```
interface IMarket {
    ID: number,
    Name: string,
    MarketDescription: string
}
interface IDepartment {
    ID: number,
    Name: string,
    DepartmentDescription: string
}
```

Is there a way to store the interfaces in an object like this?

```
var typeMap = { Markets: IMarket, Departments: IDepartment }
```

I'd like to do something like this. I'd like to dynamically set the generic type for "getQueryResults" based on a string value I pass into the constructor.

```
export class Service {
    protected baseURL = "";
    protected typeName = "";
    private typeMap = { Markets: IMarket, Departments: IDepartment }

    constructor(typeName) {
        this.baseURL = 'http://localhost/API/odata/' + typeName;

        this.currentType = typeMap[typeName];
    }
    getQueryResults(): Promise<this.currentType> {
        return new Promise<this.currentType>((resolve, reject) => {
            $.getJSON(this.baseURL, function (returnValue) {
                resolve(returnValue.value);
            });
        })
    }
}

var marketService = new Service("Markets");
var topMarket = marketService.getQueryResults();
//topMarket is an instance(?) of IMarket

var departmentService = new Service("Departments");
var topDepartment = departmentServicegetQueryResults();
//topDepartment is an instance(?) of IDepartment
```

Comment: Define "store". Do you wish to have this object at runtime? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I like to have it at runtime. I want to do something like.

Comment: No, you can't have that. Interfaces aren't present at runtime, it's for compilation only, the compiled javascript have no interfaces. If you'll explain what it is you want to do you might get alternatives.

Comment: Just added a more detailed explanation, I'm new to TypeScript, so I'm guessing there is a better way to do this, but this is just the first way I thought of to implement what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be simply solved using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), it's exactly what it's for:

```
export class Service<T> {
    protected baseURL = "";

    constructor() {
        this.baseURL = 'http://localhost/API/odata/' + typeName;
    }

    getQueryResults(): Promise<T> {
        return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            $.getJSON(this.baseURL, function (returnValue) {
                resolve(returnValue.value);
            });
        })
    }
}

var marketService = new Service<IMarket>();
var topMarket: Promise<IMarket> = marketService.getQueryResults();

var departmentService = new Service<IDepartment>();
var topDepartment: Promise<IDepartment> = departmentService.getQueryResults();
```

---

#### Edit

You can use 2 more classes to "get rid" of the need to have `Service<TYPE>` more than once (per TYPE):

```
export abstract class Service<T> {
    protected baseURL = "";

    constructor() {
        this.baseURL = 'http://localhost/API/odata/' + this.getTypeName();
    }

    getQueryResults(): Promise<T> {
        return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            $.getJSON(this.baseURL, function (returnValue) {
                resolve(returnValue.value);
            });
        })
    }

    protected abstract getTypeName(): string;
}

export class MarketsService extends Service<IMarket> {
    protected getTypeName(): string {
        return "Markets";
    }
}

export class DepartmentsService extends Service<IDepartment> {
    protected getTypeName(): string {
        return "Departments";
    }
}

var marketService = new MarketsService();
var topMarket: Promise<IMarket> = marketService.getQueryResults();

var departmentService = new DepartmentsService();
var topDepartment: Promise<IDepartment> = departmentService.getQueryResults();
```

But unlike the need to specify the type every time you use `Service`, these extra classes will be part of the compiled js, so it's a question of what's more important to you.

Comment: I was hoping to do it within the Service class. It seems weird to have to specify the type every time I create the object, since it will always be associated to the "typeName" variable I'm passing to the constructor.

Comment: For example it would always be `new Service<IMarket>("Markets");` and never something like `new Service<IMarket2>("Markets");` I just seems annoying to have to include the type in each typescript file, I'd prefer to just include it in the Services file.

Comment: Well, in your code there was no apparent use of this `typeName` other than using it to decide which type you return in the promise so I just removed it. Unfortunately you'll need to have this duplicity because, as I wrote, the interfaces are not available at runtime, but again, maybe if you'll explain more about your scenario then I (or someone else) can come up with other solutions.

Comment: `typeName` is added to `this.baseURL` in the constructor

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that, my bad. Well, I can't think of a simpler solution for you than generics, but I don't think that it's bad because tying the url path with the interface seems like idea to regret further down the road. What if tomorrow you'll want a service which should return a promise to an array of `IMarket`s?

Comment: I modified my answer with another option when using generics

Comment: Yes, I think that is probably the best option right now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a note from the TypeScript docs:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespaced-validators

> ```
> namespace Validation {
>     export interface StringValidator {
>         isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
>     }
> ```

It appears you would want:

```
namespace YourNamespace {
    export interface IMarket {
        ID: number,
        Name: string,
        MarketDescription: string
    }

    export interface IDepartment {
        ID: number,
        Name: string,
        DepartmentDescription: string
    }
}
```